# Function that computes a string from two integers?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++.When I study C++ language, I encounter some problems.The following problem is a function that computes a string from two integers.

```
string riddle (int n, int b){
       string s =" ";
       s[0]=(n%b)+'0';
       if (n>=b) s= riddle(n/b,b)+s;
       return s;
}
```

`riddle(7,8)` returns 7

`riddle(123,10)` returns 123

`riddle(40,2)` returns 10100

`riddle(100,7)` returns 202

Can anyone can explain it in detail for me? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a recursive function that converts an integer to a specific base. For example, `riddle(40, 2)` returns `10100` because:

```
40 in decimal is, 10100 in binary
```

It works by sequence of dividing `n` by `b` and putting its reminder in the result. The function returns the result as string and it works when `n` is greater that `b`.